# Activate a figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

It seems easy but I could not find any solution for opening multiple figures and save them by their name. I look for something like this:

```
fig1, ax1 = pl.subplots(1)
fig2, ax2 = pl.subplots(1)
...
pl.savefig('f1.png', fig1)
pl.savefig('f2.png', fig2)
```

usually `pl.savefig` acts on the last active figure. So how one can activate a figure and save it, then repeat the process for the rest of the figures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save an image using the figure object itself:

```
fig1.savefig(...)
```

Alternatively, you can change the current figure by calling `plt.figure(1)` to select the first figure that was create and then use `plt.savefig()`. Or, you can use `plt.figure(fig1.number)` to switch focus to `fig1`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1)
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(1)

# Can choose one of the below to change the current figure
plt.figure(1)
# plt.figure(fig1.number)

plt.savefig(...) # will save fig1
```